# Convert JSON from Notification into URL

Tags: json, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am having a bit of trouble with converting a body message I am receiving from a notification into a URL. I am getting the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (...) to 'NSURL' (...)

I am doing this the following way:

```
let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let alert = aps?["alert"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let body = alert?["body"]
let url = body as! URL
```

The JSON Structure is `aps: { alert: { body: "www.google.com"`

Question: Why is the casting failing here?

Comment: BTW - `www.google.com` is not a valid URL. To make it valid it needs include the `http:` or `https:` scheme such as `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: @rmaddy true, bad example. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` is not a `URL`. You need to create a `URL` from a `String` using the proper `URL` initializer, not by trying to cast it.

You should also write more defensive code by safely unwrapping.

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
    if let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let body = alert["body"] as? String {
            if let url = URL(string: body) {
                // do something with url
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also shorten this to:

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String : AnyObject], let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String : AnyObject], let body = alert["body"] as? String {
    if let url = URL(string: body) {
        // do something with url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does the job. Still trying to wrap my head around optionals and casting in Swift.